# How do you say "fruits of darkness" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I am writing a text where this phrase is on a big part. It will be the title, so it's important to me to got it right. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

There's a few ways to translate this. I am ignorant of the nuances, but here's my best understanding based off of minor Googling and Whitaker's Words.

Fructus Tenebrarum = The fruit/benefit/reward of darkness.

Fructus Obscuritatis = The fruit/benefit/reward of blindness/darkness/lack of understanding.

Fructus Crepesculi = The fruit/benefit/reward of twilight/darkness.

---

If you want to decline this properly in your work (I don't know your intentions) these are the ways you want to decline it.

Subject of sentence: Fructus Tenebrarum/Fructus Obscuritatis/Fructus Crepesculi

Object of sentence: Fructum Tenebrarum/Fructum Obscuritatis/Fructum Crepesculi

Indirect Object: Fructui Tenebrarum/Fructui Obscuritatis/Fructui Crepesculi

Within Prepositional Phrase: Fructu Tenebrarum/Fructu Obscuritatis/Fructu Crepesculi

Comment: Thank you very much! The nuances are that "fruits" mean the rewards which will appear from the darkness, and "darkness" will literally be the night (but also dark powers). So I think "Fructus Tenebrarum" will be right. So does your translation mean plural even thought you wrote "fruit"?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Nickimite's fine examples, there is also:

- **fructus caliginis** "fruits of darkness" (deep darkness, with a vague connotation of being in a dark nebula; gloom, blindness, calamity)
- **fructus obscuri** "fruits of darkness" (the dark, with a vague connotation of darkness covering the world from one's vision; the hidden, unknown)

I think *obscuri* is more common than *obscuritatis*.

*Tenebrarum* is excellent. It also has the advantage of being grammatically plural (even though it is just "(the) darkness" semantically), so perhaps a suggestion of powers of darkness is most easily made. It is not seldom used with ominous connotations, like the underworld.

*Crepesculi* is probably uncommon.

[Lewis & Short](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=tenebrae&filter=CUTF8) say this:

> *tenebrae* is stronger than *obscuritas*, and weaker than *caligo*

As to the form *fructus*, that can be either plural or singular (one with a final *u* pronounced long, the other short). Nickimite has given the declension of the singular. *Fructus* has a connotation of fruit one enjoys, from *fruor* "to enjoy, profit from". There is also *frux* "fruit", plural *fruges*, which is from the same root, but I believe it rather has a connotation of "usefulness".